# How can I generate a non-integer random number on cplex?

Tags: cplex

How can I generate a non-integer random number (which varies with each run) between 0 and 1 (for example   0.14)?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
int N=100000000;

float randFloat[i in 1..10]=rand(N)/N;

execute
{
  Opl.srand(new Date().getMilliseconds());
  writeln(randFloat);
}
```

will give different values each time you run

PS:

4 random functions in OPL CPLEX as can be read in https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=12f29a09-26e3-47d9-98b4-94b2c6fc4306&CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7&tab=digestviewer#bm12f29a09-26e3-47d9-98b4-94b2c6fc4306

Comment: I did as he suggested but at every launch I keep getting the same values.

Comment: Do you change the random seed at each run ?